# Am I allowed to break my lease if my landlord is stalking me?

Tags: lease

The lease has the wrong address and apartment on it. The only address on the lease is the landlords... Is this a binding contract?

Comment: Maybe you should get your landlord evicted from his apartment and move in there.  But seriously, if your landlord is stalking you, you need legal advice, which is off topic here.  We can speak generally about situations like yours, but you should talk to a lawyer.  If you can't afford one, there may be a tenant advocacy organization that can help.

Comment: Moreover, the fact that a lease has the wrong address is not evidence of stalking, nor does it make the lease invalid. If the landlord is actually illegally entering your apartment, that would not make the lease invalid, but it would probably allow you to terminate the lease.

Comment: Thank you I never thought to look for a tenant advocacy organization in my area...

Comment: I am moving out.. he has entered my apartment he follows me and comes by my work.. I just happen to notice the address on the lease..  I think you are both correct I need to get an attorney ..

Answer (score 1):

**If someone is stalking you call the police immediately.** File a report and ask to obtain a copy for your records.

Once you are safe, look online for a local lawyer that advertises free phone consultations and explain your situation; mention you have a copy of the police report. A lawyer in your state is the only one who can tell you if the contract is binding or not.